# Show categories in H3 then show sub-categories in a list

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok. I tried the code from another question:

```
<?php
    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=4&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
     }
     echo '</ul>';
?>
```

But didn't worked. Since I'll display the main categories in a H3, I did in a non-dynamic way. So yeah, It will look a LOT of PHP. And also: it's not working.

```
<h3>Automação</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=13&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
                <h3>Balanças</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=34&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>              
                <h3>Caixas Registradoras</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=42&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
                <h3>Gavetas de Dinheiro</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=45&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
                <h3>Impressoras</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=49&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
                <h3>Informática</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=57&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
                <h3>Leitores</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=61&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
                <h3>Marcas</h3>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=70&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
```

There is any way to display the main category in a H3 and the sub-categories in a one-way PHP? Because I know the problems of performance and security when I place A LOT of PHP.

Example:

```
H3> AUTOMACAO
UL
LI> SUB-CATEGORY
LI> SUB-CATEGORY
```

Comment: this is wordpress, i assume? and what is 'not working'?

Comment: @reikyoushin hi, it's WordPress.

The sub category is not showing. It's showing just the H3. And also, the H3 is static. I want to make it dynamic. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I got what you are looking for.  Basically what I created was obtaining a list of all category IDs and filtering the parent categories in an array then going through and displaying it based on your formatting.

```
<?php //Get list of parent category IDs and put it inside of $parent_categories array
    $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
    $parent_categories = array(); 
    foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) { 
        $category = get_category($cat_id);
        if ($category->parent == 0) {
            $parent_categories[] = $category->cat_ID;
        }
    }
?>
<?php //Display each parent <h3>category</h3> and <ul>subcategories</ul>
    foreach ($parent_categories as $pcat) :
        $category = get_category($pcat);
?>
        <h3><?php echo ucfirst($category->name); ?> </h3>
        <?php /*  if you want to show the full link you can use this instead
        <?php 
        $parentArgs =   array(
            'title_li'          => '',
            'include'           => $pcat
        );
        ?>
        <h3><?php wp_list_categories($parentArgs); ?></h3>

        */ ?>
        <ul>
        <?php 
            $childArgs =    array(
                'title_li'          => '',  //You could put the parent category title in here if you want
                'child_of'          =>$category->cat_ID
            );
            wp_list_categories($childArgs);
        ?>
        </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION REQUESTED:**

You could display based on the taxonomy here is an example.

```
<?php //Get list of parent category IDs and put it inside of $parent_categories array
    $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
    $parent_categories = array(); 
    foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) { 
        $category = get_category($cat_id);
        if ($category->parent == 0) {
            $parent_categories[] = $category->cat_ID;
        }
    }
?>
<?php //Display each parent <h3>category</h3> and <ul>subcategories</ul>
    foreach ($parent_categories as $pcat) :
        $category = get_category($pcat);
        if ($category->taxonomy == 'category') : //You change the 'category' to your taxonomy.
?>
            <h3><?php echo ucfirst($category->name); ?> </h3>
            <ul>
            <?php 
                $childArgs =    array(
                    'title_li'  => '',  //You could put the parent category title in here if you want
                    'child_of'  =>$category->cat_ID
                );
                wp_list_categories($childArgs);
            ?>
            </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Almost. I need to display the categories of a custom post type. But yes, It's basically what I need.

Comment: Went ahead and added additional information you have requested.  It is recommended to clearly display what you are trying to accomplish in your question.

Comment: The first solution worked fine (except that I didn't post additional information, so you get confused), but the second don't. :(

Comment: Are you using taxonomy to define your custom post type?  if ($category->taxonomy == 'category') needs to be edited based on your taxonomy.

Comment: Yes, my taxonomy is "product_cat". I tried but didn't show anything.

Comment: Why dont you try and use this instead $category->term_taxonomy_id == ID in that if statement